# The minimum degree of a polynomial function with constraints

Tags: functions, polynomials

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a polynomial function s.t. $f(\sqrt{3}-2i)=0$, $f(x)\neq 0$, and all
> the coefficients are rational numbers. What is the minimum value of
> $\deg\left(f(x)\right)$?

The problem is stated above. I noticed that if the coefficients can be real numbers, then the minimum possible value of $\deg\left(f(x)\right)$ would be $2$. The function be constructed as shown below.

---

First, because $f(\sqrt{3}-2i)=0$, so $f(\sqrt{3}+2i)=0$. Then, $f(x)=P(x)\left(x-\left(\sqrt{3}-2i\right)\right)\left(x-\left(\sqrt{3}+2i\right)\right)$, where $P(x)$ is a arbitrary polynomial that is not equal to $0$. So $f(x)=P(x)\left(x^2-2\sqrt{3}x+\left(\sqrt{3}-2i\right)\left(\sqrt{3}+2i\right)\right)=P(x)\left(x^2-2\sqrt{3}x+7\right)$.

Then, $\deg\left(f(x)\right)=\deg\left(P(x)\left(x^2-2\sqrt{3}x+7\right)\right)=\deg\left(P(x)\right)+2$, so the minimum value of $\deg\left(f(x)\right)$ is $2$, when $P(x)=k\;(k\in \mathbb{R}, k\neq0)$.

---

Now, I want to cancel the $\sqrt{3}$, which is not rational, multiplying the function$f(x)=x^2-2\sqrt{3}x+7$ by an arbitrary polynomial $Q(x)$ (the degree of $Q(x)$ is probably $1$ or $2$ ). However, assuming $Q(x)=ax+b$ would lead to $a=b=0$, making $f(x)=0$. After this point, I'm stuck.

Comment: The $0$ polynomial works, so...

Comment: Oh! I should edit the problem. Also the INTEGER part was wrong. The original problem states that the coefficients of $f(x)$ is rational.

Comment: The minimal polynomial has degree $4$. Observe that $x=\sqrt3-2i$ implies $x\overline x=7$. How does that help?

Comment: $  \left(x^2 + 7 - 2 \, \sqrt 3 \, x \; \right)  \left(x^2 + 7 + 2 \, \sqrt 3 \, x \; \right)  $  is nice